# reading and editing specific XML code in XML files through C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm trying to create a program in C# that will open several XML files all mentioned inside a `Main.xml` file, look for certain name tags, and add a postfix to them (`blabla_name`, `Blabla_unit_name`, `Location_code`, `WO_Name`). The problem is that the names are relational attributes that have varying tags depending on the file they're in. For instance, it could be `<Structure_name>` in the `structure.xml` file but it could be `<From_structure_name>` in the `equipment.xml` file.

So, what I've done is create an XML parsing program that will get all the links from the `Main.XML` file, open each file, read and find the name tags I'm looking for, and save their values (`innertext`) in a list of strings. The intention is, after reading and storing all the required values in the list, I want to iterate index by index over every file and replace the value inside the list `innertext` of `<structure_name> && <from_structure_name>` in another file. For example, with the new value + the postfix.

I've done almost 80% of the job but the thing I'm struggling with is that the postfix is added more than once. That's because I can't think of a condition that will restrict the writing method to only executing after the reading process is finished, but at the same time also executing on every file.

Here's my code:

```c#
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == null)
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a folder");
    else
    {
        string postfix = textBox2.Text;
        string location = textBox3.Text;
        string workOrder = textBox4.Text;

        List<string> contentList = new List<string>();

        if ((postfix.Length > 0) && (postfix.Length <= 2))
        {
            List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
            List<string> unitNameList = new List<string>();
            List<string> locationList = new List<string>();
            List<string> workOrderList = new List<string>();

            List<string> fileContents = new List<string>();
            // Load the document.
            String folderPath = textBox1.Text;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(folderPath + "\\Main.xml");
            int i = 0;
            XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling;
            XmlNodeList tree = root.ChildNodes;
            List<string> mainList = new List<string>();

            foreach (XmlNode node in tree)
            {
                mainList.Add(tree.Item(i).InnerText);
                string name = mainList[i];
                var fileName = folderPath + "\\" + name;

                XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
                doc1.Load(fileName);

                GetName(fileName, nameList);
                if (nameList.Count > 0 )
                    ReplaceText(fileName, nameList, postfix);

                GetUnitName(fileName, unitNameList);
                if (unitNameList.Count > 0)
                    ReplaceText(fileName, unitNameList, postfix);

                GetLocation(fileName, locationList);
                if (locationList.Count > 0)
                    ReplaceText(fileName, locationList, location);

                GetWorkOrder(fileName, workOrderList);
                if (workOrderList.Count>0)
                   ReplaceText(fileName, workOrderList, workOrder);

                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter atleast 1 character or 2 at maximum for the postfix.");
        }
    }
}

public void GetName(string url, List<string> list)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(url);
    string search = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(search + "_NAME");
    List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        if (nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < nodeList.Count)
            {
                if (nodeList.Item(i) != null)
                {
                    var xmlNode = nodeList.Item(i);
                    if (xmlNode != null) innerList.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                        string oldName = innerList[i];
                    list.Add(oldName);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

public void GetUnitName(string url, List<string> list)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(url);
    string search = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(search + "_UNIT_NAME");
    List<string> innerList = new List<string>();

    if (nodeList.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < nodeList.Count)
        {
            if (nodeList.Item(i) != null)
            {
                var xmlNode = nodeList.Item(i);
                if (xmlNode != null) innerList.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                    string oldName = innerList[i];
                list.Add(oldName);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
}

public void GetLocation(string url, List<string> list)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(url);
    string search = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("LOCATION_CODE");
    List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        if (nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < nodeList.Count && i != nodeList.Count)
            {
                if (nodeList.Item(i) != null)
                {
                    var xmlNode = nodeList.Item(i);
                    if (xmlNode != null) innerList.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                        string oldName = innerList[i];

                    list.Add(oldName);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }   
}


public void GetWorkOrder(string url, List<string> list)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(url);
    string search = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("WO_NAME");
    List<string> innerList = new List<string>();

    if (nodeList.Count > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < nodeList.Count)
        {
            if (nodeList.Item(i) != null)
            {
                var xmlNode = nodeList.Item(i);
                if (xmlNode != null) innerList.Add(xmlNode.InnerText);
                    string oldName = innerList[i];
                list.Add(oldName);
                i++;
            }
        }

    } 
}

public void ReplaceText(string url, List<string> list, string text)
{
    string content = File.ReadAllText(url);
    string old;
    string newText;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.Count)
    {
        old = list[i];
        newText = old + text;

        content = content.Replace(old, newText);
        File.WriteAllText(url, content);
        i++;
    }
}
```

And here's a part of an XML file I'm working with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<INVENTORY>
    <STRUCTURE>
        <ACCOUNT_CODE>85C</ACCOUNT_CODE>
        <ANCILLARYROLE>0</ANCILLARYROLE>
        <AVERAGE_FLOOR_HEIGHT>0</AVERAGE_FLOOR_HEIGHT>
        <CATEGORY_NAME>CAPPED</CATEGORY_NAME>
        <DEPTH_PLACED>0</DEPTH_PLACED>
        <DIAMETER>0</DIAMETER>
        <ENABLED>1</ENABLED>
        <ENDING_FLOOR>0</ENDING_FLOOR>
        <GEOMETRY>X="612001.739290147" Y="2615034.85310004"</GEOMETRY>
        <GROUND_FLOOR_NUMBER>0</GROUND_FLOOR_NUMBER>
        <GROUND_HEIGHT>0</GROUND_HEIGHT>
        <HEIGHT>0</HEIGHT>
        <INSTALLED_COST>0</INSTALLED_COST>
        <INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE>IPL</INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE>
        <LENGTH>0</LENGTH>
        <LOCATION_CODE>LOC_105441</LOCATION_CODE>
        <MANUFACTURER_CODE>UNSPECIFIED</MANUFACTURER_CODE>
        <MATERIAL_COST>0</MATERIAL_COST>
        <MAX_POWER_REQUIREMENT>0</MAX_POWER_REQUIREMENT>
        <MODEL_UUID>{18E86703-E7D6-4755-9B15-11597BA96EB6}</MODEL_UUID>
        <OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE>OWN</OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CODE>
        <PRODUCT_LINE_CODE>UNSPECIFIED</PRODUCT_LINE_CODE>
        <REF_TYPE>NONE</REF_TYPE>
        <REF_UUID>{35454233-F799-44E5-B8FA-A1D2BB134DC2}</REF_UUID>
        <ROTATION>0</ROTATION>
        <STARTING_FLOOR>0</STARTING_FLOOR>
        <STRUCTURE_NAME>CAP:CAP::380465</STRUCTURE_NAME>
        <STRUCTURE_REF_NAME>End Cap</STRUCTURE_REF_NAME>
        <TRANSMEDIA_DEMAND>0</TRANSMEDIA_DEMAND>
        <TYPE_NAME>CAPPED</TYPE_NAME>
        <UNITS>0</UNITS>
        <UUID>{AB826169-F95A-42C6-BD95-0A4CD153F03A}</UUID>
        <VOLUME>0</VOLUME>
        <WEIGHT>0</WEIGHT>
        <WIDTH>0</WIDTH>
        <WO_NAME>exp-test</WO_NAME>
    </STRUCTURE>
</INVENTORY>
```

Comment: Is what you are trying to do just, for example, "change all structures named `CAP:CAP::380465` to `CAP:CAP::380466`"? How big are the files you are working with?

Comment: no because CAP:CAP::380466 will most likely already exist, I want to add a post fix to every structure name included in the other files, For example, <structure_name>CAP:CAP::380465</structure_name>  might exist that way in the structure.xml file. And it might exist in other files as <from_structure_name>CAP:CAP::380465</from_structure_name> in equipment.xml. so I wanna take all the values of names, unit_names, location, wo_order. and store them in a list, then look for each value in that list and change it in the files because they will have different nametags

Comment: It still sounds to me like what you are trying to do is change the value of a bunch of related entities. Can you update your question with a minimal set of example inputs and expected outputs? e.g. only include the relevant tags and provide sample main.xml and equipment.xml files.

Comment: I've figured it out and it works perfectly, thanks everyone for trying to help :)